# Highcharts compare different dates ranges

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to use highstock to compare two different time ranges together.

For example, for two data sets, one that shows the max temp for each day in Jan and the other one for Feb (for example), I'd like them to be shown one above the other, with the x-axis being the "same" one for both.

I can't do it with categories, because the data is being fed automatically, so each data point has its own time, so the x-axis is datetime.

I wanted to know if it was possible to simply have two graphs overlapping, with one graph having the normal x-axis at the bottom, and the other one having on top of the graph, so even when the data is for different times, it's shown overlapping. I can't find this problem anywhere.

Comment: you need something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/4b33pvc2/15/ ??

Comment: You can also use for each serie separated xAxis with different scale / interval and other options. The rule of using is excatly the same as with yAxis. You need to define array of axis and set index in particular serie.

Comment: @NishithKantChaturvedi yes, but with different values for each xAxis

Comment: @SebastianBochan where can I read about that?

Comment: You can find information in our documentaiton, here http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on this thread. Hope it helps!

[Overlay 2 series of data of different length with highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274886/overlay-2-series-of-data-of-different-length-with-highcharts)

Answer (score -2):

[Essential Chart](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/chart) can be used with different date ranges with multiple axes. [example source](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/yqbetifx)

The [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) provides the whole suite of products for free if you qualify.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.